# How to get column list with comma separate values on data-table load in some function

Tags: jquery, datatables

I want to pass the column list with comma separated values(string) on some customize function.

For ex.

```
function newExportAction() {
    var table = $('#tblfiles').DataTable();
    var SearchData = table.search();
    var OrderData = table.order();
}
```

- these are used for getting search and order values. but I also need the columns list as string value.

Comment: Can you provide more details?

Comment: Like if i am using table.columns().names() - It shows error.

Comment: `tblfiles` points to some HTML Table Element ? and you want table columns as comma-separated list ?

Comment: tblfiles is just simple table id where my data-table shows with rows data. and i want comma separated values for those data-table columns to pass on my custom function.

Comment: why dont you get all the `th` and concatenate the strings?

Comment: Because my column names and th titiles are different.

Answer (score 0):

Use code below, it works fine:

```js
$(function(){
  var table =  $('#tblfiles').DataTable();
    
  var names = col_names_string($('#tblfiles'));  

  $('#nam').text(names);
  console.log(names);
})

function col_names_string(tbl) {
        var len = tbl.find('th').length;
        var str = tbl.find('th').eq(0).text(); 
        for (var i = 1; i<len; i++) {    
            str += ',' + tbl.find('th').eq(i).text();
        };
  return str;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/js/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.js"></script> 
<div id="nam"></div> 
<br>
<table id="tblfiles">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>EEE</th>
      <th>WWW</th>
      <th>QQQ</th>
      <th>RRRR</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>5</td>
      <td>6</td>
      <td>1</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Implementation to your function is next:

```
function newExportAction() {
    var table = $('#tblfiles').DataTable();
    var SearchData   = table.search();
    var OrderData    = table.order();
    var ColumnNames  = col_names_string($('#tblfiles'));
}
    function col_names_string(tbl) {
            var len = tbl.find('th').length;
            var str = tbl.find('th').eq(0).text(); 
            for (var i = 1; i<len; i++) {    
                str += ',' + tbl.find('th').eq(i).text();
            };
      return str;
    }
```